# How to access string as character value

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/ZsALO8oF3W

I want to traverse a string and return the character values. How do I, not return the numeric values per each letter, and return the actual characters?

Now I am getting this

```
 0 72 72
 1 101 101
 2 108 108
 3 108 108
 4 111 111
```

My desired output would be

```
 0 h h
 1 e e
 2 l l
 3 l l
 4 o o

 package main

 import "fmt"

 func main() {

    str := "Hello"
    for i, elem := range str {
        fmt.Println(i, str[i], elem)
    }

    for elem := range str {
        fmt.Println(elem)
    }   
 }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> [For statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code
>   points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive
>   iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of
>   successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second
>   value, of type rune, will be the value of the corresponding code
>   point. If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the
>   second value will be 0xFFFD, the Unicode replacement character, and
>   the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    str := "Hello"
    for _, r := range str {
        c := string(r)
        fmt.Println(c)
    }
    fmt.Println()
    for i, r := range str {
        fmt.Println(i, r, string(r))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
H
e
l
l
o

0 72 H
1 101 e
2 108 l
3 108 l
4 111 o
```

Comment: Just to reiterate - the index returned may not be contiguous if there are unicode chars involved. If that is needed you need to type cast string to rune array `var threeRuneSlice []rune = []rune(oneString)` and use range  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66517852/429476

Answer (score 6):

package main
Use Printf to indicate you want to print characters.

```
import "fmt"

func main() {

        str := "Hello"
        for i, elem := range str {
                fmt.Printf("%d %c %c\n", i, str[i], elem)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are iterating over the characters in the string is workable (although str[i] and elem are the duplicative of each other).  You have the right data.

In order to get it to display correctly, you just need to output with the right formatting (i.e. interpreted as a unicode character rather than an int).

Change:

```
fmt.Println(i, str[i], elem)
```

to:

```
fmt.Printf("%d %c %c\n", i, str[i], elem)
```

`%c` is *the character represented by the corresponding Unicode code point* per the Printf doc: http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/