# Golang converting from rune to string

Tags: string, parsing, go, unicode, rune

I have the following code, it is supposed to cast a `rune` into a `string` and print it. However, I am getting undefined characters when it is printed. I am unable to figure out where the bug is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "text/scanner"
)

func main() {
    var b scanner.Scanner
    const a = `a`
    b.Init(strings.NewReader(a))
    c := b.Scan()
    fmt.Println(strconv.QuoteRune(c))
}
```

Comment: Any reason that force you to use scanner? I mean you trying to figure out how "text/scanner" work or you just simple want to convert rune to string?

Comment: `string(r)` to set a rune to a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739051/12817546. `[]rune("abc") ` to set a string to a rune. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739051/12817546.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

That's because you used [`Scanner.Scan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/#Scanner.Scan) to read a `rune` but it does something else. `Scanner.Scan()` can be used to read *tokens* or `rune`s of special tokens controlled by the `Scanner.Mode` bitmask, and it returns special constants form the [`text/scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/) package, not the read rune itself.

To read a single `rune` use [`Scanner.Next()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/#Scanner.Next) instead:

```
c := b.Next()
fmt.Println(c, string(c), strconv.QuoteRune(c))
```

Output:

```
97 a 'a'
```

If you just want to convert a single `rune` to `string`, use a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). `rune` is alias for `int32`, and converting integer numbers to `string`:

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

So:

```
r := rune('a')
fmt.Println(r, string(r))
```

Outputs:

```
97 a
```

Also to loop over the runes of a `string` value, you can simply use the `for ... range` construct:

```
for i, r := range "abc" {
    fmt.Printf("%d - %c (%v)\n", i, r, r)
}
```

Output:

```
0 - a (97)
1 - b (98)
2 - c (99)
```

Or you can simply convert a `string` value to `[]rune`:

```
fmt.Println([]rune("abc")) // Output: [97 98 99]
```

There is also [`utf8.DecodeRuneInString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRuneInString).

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/y6_yDVtoQJ).

**Note:**

Your original code (using `Scanner.Scan()`) works like this:

1. You called [`Scanner.Init()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/#Scanner.Init) which sets the Mode (`b.Mode`) to `scanner.GoTokens`.
2. Calling `Scanner.Scan()` on the input (from `"a"`) returns `scanner.Ident` because `"a"` is a valid Go identifier:

   ```
   c := b.Scan()
   if c == scanner.Ident {
       fmt.Println("Identifier:", b.TokenText())
   }

   // Output: "Identifier: a"
   ```

Comment: you can also use "%#U" as a format tag  `fmt.Printf("%v\t%#U\t%s\n", r, r, strconv.QuoteRune(r))` prints `51      U+0033 '3'      '3'`

Comment: For newbies, need example without `fmt.Println`, just how to get value into variable or as function return.

Answer (score 4):

This simple code works in converting a rune to a string

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%c", rune)
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but here's a []rune to string function:

```
func runesToString(runes []rune) (outString string) {
    // don't need index so _
    for _, v := range runes {
        outString += string(v)
    }
    return
}
```

yes, there is a named return but I think it's ok in this case as it reduces the number of lines and the function is only short

Comment: `[]rune` to `string` conversion is supported natively by the spec, this is completely unnecessary and slow. Instead use a simple conversion: `outString := string(runes)`

Comment: @icza enlightening comment. I quoted you here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739051/12817546.

Answer (score 3):

Since I came to this question searching for rune and string and char, thought this may help newbies like me

```
// str := "aഐbc"
// testString(str)
func testString(oneString string){

    //string to byte slice - No sweat -just type cast it
    // As string  IS A byte slice
    var twoByteArr []byte = []byte(oneString)

    // string to rune Slices - No sweat 
    // string IS A slice of runes 
    var threeRuneSlice []rune = []rune(oneString)

   // Hmm! String seems to have a dual personality it is both a slice of bytes and
   // a slice of runes - yeah - read on
    
    // A rune slice can be convered to string -
    // No sweat - as string == rune slice
    var thrirdString string = string(threeRuneSlice)
    
    // There is a catch here and that is in printing "characters", using for loop and range 
    
    fmt.Println("Chars in oneString")
    for i,r := range oneString {
        fmt.Printf(" %d  %v  %c ",i,r,r) //you may not get index 0,1,2,3 here  
        // since the range runs specially over strings  https://blog.golang.org/strings
    }
    
    fmt.Println("\nChars in threeRuneSlice")
    for i,r := range threeRuneSlice {
        fmt.Printf(" %d  %v  %c ",i,r,r) // i = 0,1,2,4 , perfect!!
        // as runes are made up of 4 bytes (rune is int32 and byte in unint8
        // and a set of bytes is used to represent a rune which is used to 
       // represent  UTF characters == the REAL CHARECTER 
    }

    fmt.Println("\nValues in oneString ")
    for j := 0; j < len(oneString); j++ {
        fmt.Printf(" %d %v ",j,oneString[j]) // No you cannot get charecters if you iterate through string in this way
        // as you are going over bytes here - not runes
    }
    fmt.Println("\nValues in twoByteArr")
    for j := 0; j < len(twoByteArr); j++ {
        fmt.Printf(" %d=%v ",j,twoByteArr[j]) // == same as above
    }
    
    fmt.Printf("\none - %s, two %s, three %s\n",oneString,twoByteArr,thrirdString)
}
```

And some more pointless demo https://play.golang.org/p/tagRBVG8k7V
adapted from https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/84GCvDBhpbg/m/Tt6089MPFQAJ

to show that the 'characters' are encoded with one to up to 4 bytes depending on the unicode code point

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```golang
// rune => string
fmt.Printf("%c\n", 65) // A
fmt.Println(string(rune(0x1F60A))) // 
fmt.Println(string([]rune{0x1F468, 0x200D, 0x1F9B0})) // ‍

// string => rune
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatUint(uint64([]rune("")[0]), 16)) // 1f60a
fmt.Printf("%U\n", '') // U+1F60A
fmt.Printf("%U %U %U\n", '', '‍', '') // U+1F468 U+200D U+1F9B0
```

[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/3Lzw91QbS_F)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string function

```
string(a)
```

[Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/4tExzsxi1h4)